# How can I implement horizontal scroll on drag functionality on text that has "text-overflow: ellipsis" without the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have several lines of text, each of them is wrapped inside fixed-width paragraph tag. They are different in length. So I truncate the lines with "text-overflow: ellipsis" and hide the scroll-bar with "overflow: hidden".

HTML:

```
<p>This is a short line</p>
<p>This line is a little bit longer</p>
<p>This is a really very long very long very long line</p>
<p>This is a short line</p>
<p>This line is a little bit longer</p>
<p>This is a really very long very long very long line</p>
<p>This is a short line</p>
<p>This line is a little bit longer</p>
<p>This is a really very long very long very long line</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I would like to be able to scroll on drag to see what the full line is, but without displaying the scroll-bar.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/k4mhohc8/) a jsfiddle with default scroll-bar, which allows me to do scrolling, and [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/751rz9xa/) a jsfiddle with "overflow: hidden" property, that truncates the lines the way I need, but without scrolling.

So, what are possible ways to hide the scroll-bar but keep scroll-on-drag functionality? Can it be done with pure HTML and CSS or I would have to write JS or even jQuery?

Comment: Are you loking for something like this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k4mhohc8/3)   check the red text.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! But is it possible to keep the three dots that "text-overflow: ellipsis" adds? It's not necessary for me, but I'm curious...

Comment: @Alex do you need that functionality on all browsers? including mobiles?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately *No* but you can play with that `custom-scroll` and your `CSS` to achieve that.

Comment: @neoDev No, not on mobiles, and not on legacy IE.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay OK, thank you!

Comment: And you need exactly the "drag-to-scroll" functionality, or you just want to normally scroll with the mouse wheel (for mouses supporting horizontal scroll)?

Comment: @neoDev Yes, I need drag-to-scroll functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I write a simple method for you, You can develope it

```
var clicked = 0;
var regular = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").mousedown(function(){
        clicked = 1;
        regular = 0;
    });
    $("p").mouseup(function(){
        clicked = 0;
    });
    $("p").mousemove(function(event, a, b){
        var p = $(this);
        if( event.offsetX > (p.width() - 30)  && clicked == 1){
            console.log((regular - 1));
            regular--;
            p.css({"text-indent":(regular) + "px"});
        }
        if( event.offsetX < 30 && event.offsetX > 0   && clicked == 1){
            console.log((regular - 1));
            regular++;
            p.css({"text-indent":(regular) + "px"});
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/k4mhohc8/4/